# bulk update on firebase with angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase

My goal is to update 400000 records in a firebase flat structure , in a angular application.

My controller contains the following, and it's not updating the structure

```
var obj = fbutil.syncArray('detect');
...
$scope.gridOptions.data = obj;
...
$scope.xupdate =function() {
$scope.gridOptions.data.forEach(function(ob) {
  switch (ob.robot){
    case "PKO-PI5":
     ob.location = "WAT-JLB";
     break;  
    case "PKO-NATH":
     ob.location = "WAT-FBG";
     break; 
    case "PKO-FRAN":
      ob.location="KRA-DUM";
      break;
    default:
      ob.location="WAT-UKN";
  }
  obj.$save(ob.location); 
});
};
```

if someone can unlock my brain, i'll be very happy

Best regards.

Philippe

Comment: without any troubleshootiing info provided , not sure what sort of solutions you were expecting. Seems like a lot of requests to run...might consider throttling them a bit

Comment: seems nothing happens for records who don't have existing location So i extend the question is $save able to add "new field in record" or is it updating preexisting field ??

Comment: No idea what this means or what your additional follow-up comment means here. Please consider reading [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it's likely to save you a lot of energy getting to the source of the problem and help the community contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

move the `obj.$save(ob.location);` outside the forEach and do something like this:

```
obj.$save(ob.location)
  .then(
    function(ref){console.log("saved");},
    function(error){console.log("error");}
  )
```

Comment: when i'm working on a subset with 100 records where location exist, and 900 record where location doesnt exist , the $save return 900 errors "could determine its key: WAT-JLB". So i suppose that i need to introduce the ad-hoc key somewhere in the save object. but i cannot find a very explicit syntax of $save

Comment: this is a good day,   i solve the problem,   by changing
obj.$save(ob.location)   in   obj.$save(ob)  in this case firebase know the id of the record, and can save it